# How to remove zero entries in a DFM when the matrix is too big for usual manipulation?

Tags: r, dataframe, lda, quanteda

I have the following problem: I converted a corpus into a dfm and this dfmm has some zero entries that I need to remove before fitting a LDA model. I would usually do as follows:

```
OutDfm <- dfm_trim(dfm(corpus, tolower = TRUE, remove = c(stopwords("english"), stopwords("german"), stopwords("french"), stopwords("italian")), remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_separators = TRUE, stem = TRUE, verbose = TRUE), min_docfreq = 5)

Creating a dfm from a corpus input...
   ... lowercasing
   ... found 272,912 documents, 112,588 features
   ... removed 613 features
   ... stemming features (English)
, trimmed 27491 feature variants
   ... created a 272,912 x 84,515 sparse dfm
   ... complete. 
Elapsed time: 78.7 seconds.


# remove zero-entries
raw.sum=apply(OutDfm,1,FUN=sum)
which(raw.sum == 0)
OutDfm = OutDfm[raw.sum!=0,]
```

However, when I try to perform the last operations I get: `Error in asMethod(object) :  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105` hinting at the fact the the matrix is too large to be manipulated.

Is there anyone who has met and solved this issue before? Any alternative strategy to remove the 0 entries?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `apply` with `sum` transforms the dfm from a sparse matrix into a dense matrix for calculating the row sum.

Either use `slam::row_sums` since slam functions work on sparse matrices, but better yet, just use `quantada::dfm_subset` to select all the documents with more than 0 tokens.

```
dfm_subset(OutDfm, ntoken(OutDfm) > 0)
```

Example to show how it works with ntokens > 5000:

```
library(quanteda)
x <- corpus(data_corpus_inaugural)
x <- dfm(x)
x
Document-feature matrix of: 58 documents, 9,360 features (91.8% sparse) and 4 docvars.
                 features
docs              fellow-citizens  of the senate and house representatives : among vicissitudes
  1789-Washington               1  71 116      1  48     2               2 1     1            1

# subset based on amount of tokens.
dfm_subset(x, ntoken(x) > 5000)
Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 9,360 features (84.1% sparse) and 4 docvars.
               features
docs            fellow-citizens  of the senate and house representatives : among vicissitudes
  1841-Harrison              11 604 829      5 231     1               4 1     3            0
```